# when the character flips over, it turns black

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I decided to make a simple light in my game and I had a problem.When the main character turns around, he turns completely black.can you tell me how to make sure that the character does not turn black?

here are the screenshots:
not inverted
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVM7j.png)
inverted
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o1Oq.png)

here is the part of the code that flips the character:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    
    public Vector2 moveVector; 
    public bool faceRight = true;

    void Update()
    {    
        Reflect();           
    }
    
    void Reflect()
    {
        if ((moveVector.x > 0 && !faceRight) || (moveVector.x < 0 && faceRight))
        {
            transform.localScale *= new Vector2(-1, 1);
            faceRight = !faceRight;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you just want the visuals to be affected, would [FlipX](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html) be enough?

Comment: That is because instead of rotating you are changing the local scale. Try using transform.Rotate instead (;